# Getting the tensor values of a layer after calling model.predict once

Tags: python, keras-layer

How would i get the tensor of the output activations of one of the layers in a neural network after running the following code.

```
  x= model.predict(frame)
```

Comment: If you want to have reliable code for the future, you may want to the Keras' functional API and add an auxiliary output: https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/

Comment: There is a study i am conducting and i need to know the activations of the middle layer in an auto encoder after every predict

Comment: Then go for the functional API :)

Comment: Thankyou , i will read the document...but it would really help if you posted a code example, if you are unable to its still fine and thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a short example of how you could do it using [Keras' functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/):

```
inputs = Input(shape=(10,))
x = Dense(5)(inputs)
latent_outputs = Dense(2)(x)
x = Dense(5)(latent_outputs)
outputs = Dense(10)(x)

encoder = Model(inputs, latent_outputs)
autoencoder = Model(inputs, outputs)

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
autoencoder.fit(np.zeros((10, 10)), np.zeros((10, 10)))

latent_output = encoder.predict(np.zeros((1, 10)))
print(latent_output)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60475548/tying-an-external-numpy-arrays-values-to-a-dense-layers-activation   Please take a look at that question as well..they are connected..thankyou!